# Linking to a download in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have to create a online time-table for the school. The part what is troubling me at the moment is not to be able to download a file by clicking on the filename.

I try to download a file by clicking on a button or a link with html/php maybe javascript but for javascript I should somehow combine php and javascript because javascript has no readfile-function.

Some of my attempts:

```
<a href="dateiupload/testmove.txt">Download</a>
```

This just shows the content of the file in the web browser but I am not able to download it. The content of my `testmove.txt` is `testmove123`, so I just see the text `testmove123` in my browser.

Another example:
Javascript:

```
function download(file)
{
    window.location=file;
}
```

+html:

```
<input type="button" value="Download" onClick="download('dateiupload/testmove.txt')" >
```

Makes the same.

Another example:
Javascript:

```
function download(path) 
{
    var ifrm = document.getElementById("frame");
    ifrm.src = path;
}
```

+html:

```
<iframe id="frame" style="display:none"></iframe>
<a href="javascript:download('/dateiupload/testmove.txt')">download</a>
```

By clicking on "Download" the javascript function starts but nothing else happens and I see the same site.

Another example (with php):
Javascript:

```
function download(path) 
{
    var ifrm = document.getElementById(frame);
    ifrm.src = "download.php?path="+path;
}
```

+html (same as above):

```
<iframe id="frame" style="display:none"></iframe>
<a href="javascript:download('/dateiupload/testmove.txt')">download</a>
```

+php (the reason my its more or less working):

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET['path']);
readfile($_GET['path']);
```

This solution doesn't wait for a click from me and starts the download by starting the site.

A working solution I thought about would be to link to another site where the download automatically starts but its absolutely not how it have to be. I use `$_POST` variables on the site and I lose them when I leave the site and I can't come back after the download.
It must start the download by clicking on the filename.

Comment: Looks like you've put some work into this issue and also this post! Good on you! I think that the reason you are getting a few downvotes is because of the "noise" in your post. Anything that is not directly connected to the technical problem at hand is considered to distract from the main issue and is usually referred to as "noise". I'll go ahead and clean the post up for you to give you a better idea of how to post questions that are received well by the community.

Comment: `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET['path']);` This is pure evil if you don't validate the input against a list of downloadable files

Comment: There is also the html5 download attribute, unfortunately browser support is currently still lacking: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download straight from the anchor tag by using the 'download' attribute. 
`<a href="dateiupload/testmove.txt" download>Download</a>` 
The filename of the downloaded file will be `testmove.txt` by default. 

You can change the filename like this. 

`<a href="dateiupload/testmove.txt" download="ExampleFileName">Download</a>` 
More Details at [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)

Comment: No problem! :) I too have been foiled by this issue, only to have this ridiculously simple solution suggested after days of searching.

Comment: @BlubbBlubb - please note that this feature is [not supported by all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) for example IE or safari (including iOS)- I guess that might matter to you depending on your requirements.

Comment: @tinkerbot +1 good answer! I'd recommend using a reference other than W3schools. In the past [there has been some controversy](http://www.w3fools.com/) regarding that site. I'd recommend using something like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

Comment: That's a good point. This solution should be fine for `Chrome` `Opera` and `Firefox` , but for `IE` you would have to use some sort of server side code, such as the PHP suggested below by @Lix

Comment: Good advice, @Lix , will take that onboard in future.

Answer (score 1):

You were correct to use those headers - as you can see, the file *is* being downloaded. The only problem now is to have it download *when* you want it to.

For a very simple solution, I would suggest setting up a `download.php` file that will be the page you download all files from. You would setup a `GET` parameter for this file and the URL would look something like this:

```
http://your-cool-site.com/download.php?filename=textmove.txt
```

Now inside `download.php`, you'll read that `GET` parameter which will be a filename, and then pass it eventually to the `readfile` function. **This is the stage that you should think about enforcing some level of security as passing a path directly to the function could give people access to files that they shouldn't be looking at! Think about limiting the actual downloadable files to a limited selection of files or paths you know to be "safe" for people to download.**

You'll also need to use the file name in the headers (and possibly even the size of the file to support displaying progress of the download).

Once you have this `download.php` file ready, you can place links to it from other pages in a very similar way that you have now:

```
<a href="download.php?filename=testmove.txt">Download File</a>
```

Clicking on this link will make the request to `download.php` and when it gets the appropriate headers, the download will start.